# Put a button over an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I'm newbie in Android.

I would like to know if it's possible to put a button or another component over an ImageView. I've tried setting the image as a background image of a LinearLayout, but when I change between landscape and portrait mode, the image porportions are changed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Comment: ConstraintLayout is the answer. It has properties like layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf or layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf that let you set elements inside of another elements with margins. There are answers on this post that teach how to use ConstraintLayout, scroll down for it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Don't put the image as a background, you don't have any control on how the image is scaled. Instead, create a RelativeLayout, and put an ImageView as one of the child, and you can place anything (buttons etc) as other RelativeLayout children.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <ImageView (your image) ...>
    <Button (the button you want) ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope I could improve my android knowledge and help so many others,

Comment: It seems like the order in the resource matters, putting the ImageView after the Button did not work for me, but the above order did.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code... it's Help you....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:orientation="vertical"   
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

 <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/imageviewMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="Path "
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/but2" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this Code .....

In that give paramater in button to set your Button Position....

```
android:layout_margin or android:layout_alignParent
```

And also give Path of Image....

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to do it,http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way to do it is to use a `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy using the `ConstraintLayout`.

1. Set the constraints of the `Button` to the `ImageView`.
2. Drag the `Button` anywhere you want over the `ImageView` to position it.
3. XML code will be autogenerated.

[image: Button over an ImageView]

Answer (score 1):

For those using Constraint Layout: Just use an ImageView and add its constraints from all the four side to Parent and than add the other views as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/food"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imagebtn_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_24"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imagebtn_call"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_call_24"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/expdate_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_date"
                android:background="#E2E3E4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imagebtn_address"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="#E2E3E4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/test_foodname"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imagebtn_address"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imagebtn_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_24"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

> Note: Replace the drawables added with your own.

Comment: Your solution is the best of this post, I'm sorry there are other answers with more up votes, thanks dude