# How to display pop up menu for Dynamically created Imageviews

Tags: java, android

I am Creating a ImageViews dynamically now i need to display pop up menu if click the ImageView. 
ex: In that pop up i will add download. If i click that download button respective Image should download.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about putting a button on an imageview...take a look at this answer:
[Put a button over an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306453/put-a-button-over-an-imageview)

As for making a popup appear on button click, use dialogfragments.

Comment: Yes I will take care of that and now my problem is I need to display pop up menu for Dynamically created images.

Comment: DialogFragments create popups.
Do this:
1. make your activity extend FragmentActivity.
2. in the button's onClick() listener, make a dialogfragment and show() it.
3. make a button in the dialogfragment that you can use to dismiss it.

Comment: I am using List view and custom adapter. In List item 1 I am displaying several Images related to groups. like that I am displaying Group with image. Here I need to display pop up If i click that image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097723/adding-a-onclicklistener-to-listview-android

Take a look at this. Also, if the answer helped, please accept it by clicking on the tick mark on the left. :-)