# Can't see Button over fullscreen Imageview

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to show a button over a fullscreen image. [I tried to use RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306453/put-a-button-over-an-imageview) as shown in this question but I cannot see the Button.

Can someone tell me why this code isn't working?

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pitchImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/gaa_pitch"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:id="@+id/stopwatchButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Apologies if this qualifies as a duplicate question.

**EDIT**:
Screenshots of the activity.

[Android design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woS3Y.png)

[Emulator at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ1ZY.png)

Comment: can you post screen shot of it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pitchImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/gaa_pitch"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:id="@+id/stopwatchButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend you can use `FrameLayout` alternatively ,and checkout this site : [Android Frame Layout](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pitchImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/desert_road"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/stopwatchButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common "problem".
You can try a couple of things:

1. Invalidate caches and restart Android Studio, or just restart without invalidating
2. Try the `Run -> Clean and rerun` option
3. Or the `Build -> Clean project` or `Build -> Rebuild Project` options

When you are done, run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working, I can't exactly explain what fixed it but these are the steps I took:

1. Utilised a content and activity split. (to get an example of this create a basic activity in android studio).
2. I deleted other versions of the layout files in the version compatible folders (such as "layout-v24").
3. I also used "Clean" and "Rebuild" project options whenever I made a change to my code.

activity xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/content_record_game"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my content.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pitchImageView"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_of_a_gaa_pitch"
    android:src="@drawable/gaa_pitch"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:id="@+id/stopwatchButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```