# Android - Create Scrolling buttons on top of Imageview

Tags: android

I have an activity with an ImageView that is bigger then the screen so it's inside a ScrollLayout.

I want to create buttons on top this imageView but:
- How can I place the buttons on the image if I don't see the whole image?
for example, I'm attaching an image that the green color represents the imageView and the red boxes represents the buttons. how can I put all the buttons on the image if it's scrollable?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try one of these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211484/how-to-place-buttons-over-image-in-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306453/put-a-button-over-an-imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can make both the image and the buttons scrollable by using e.g. a `FrameLayout` as the direct child of the `ScrollView`. So your xml would look like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button .../>

        <Button .../>

        <Button .../>

    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: but how can I put the buttons in custom places? I have an image that has red squares on it, on different places, so I want to create the buttons on top of those red squares.

Comment: Do you know the pixel coordinates of the red squares? Or are you trying to compute them at runtime?

Comment: I can get the coordinates , but it would be different on different screen resolutions no?