# how to add a button and other elements on a background image in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a background image in Android studio. But I also want to add a button on the icture. however, when i drag the button element onto the background image, it doesn't appears on the Image. what should i do?
I want the background image and the button to come on the same screen.

Comment: Show your xml code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put a button over an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306453/put-a-button-over-an-imageview)

Comment: Thank You, the Problem has been solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Use constraint layout or relative layout. For more info
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative